# Centos 7 NetworkManager removes conection profile when device disappears and does not recreate when it reappears

Tags: centos, networking, rhel, network-interface, networkmanager

I have a software application running on CentOS 7 that creates an IP TUN network interface. I want to configure it with a static IP such that whenever the TUN interface appears it is configured. I have made the following ifcfg config:

```
[vagrant@nclc-centos7-vm ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-rf0 
BOOTPROTO=static
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
DEVICE=rf0
NAME=rf0
TYPE=tun
IPADDR=192.168.88.0
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=yes
ONBOOT=yes
HOTPLUG=yes
```

With this config in place everything works when I run

```
sudo systemctl restart network
```

But if I restart the software application the TUN interface looses the configuration.
If I do

```
nmcli monitor
```

While restarting network the first time it prints the following:

```
rf0: connection profile created
rf0: connected
rf0: using connection 'rf0'
rf0: connection profile changed
```

If I restart my application it prints the following:

```
rf0: device removed
rf0: connection profile changed
rf0: connection profile changed
rf0: connection profile removed
rf0: device created
rf0: unavailable
rf0: disconnected
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the interface configured when it first appears (ala hotplug) using NetworkManager/ifcfg without having to restart the network service.

Comment: I should mention that on Ubuntu Server 22.04 I was able to achieve the desired behavior by adding "optional: true" in the netplan yaml configuration

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the commands being used to create it,  but you may need to bring the device online.  After the device fails try  nmcli connection up rf0 - if that works can add it to the creation process.